# Any way to covert html into readable format in java?

Tags: java

I have some emails whose content is in html format and I want to save in database in readable format any inputs.

Also i have got emails dumped in a text file and i need to extract data from it.Any inputs .All in java

Comment: Do you want to remove html tags from the doc?

Comment: Have you tried ANYTHING yet or is this more like "i got a task, please do the coding stuff for me"

Comment: I find HTML to be pretty 'readable'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0424.html) describes three ways to extract the data

- using a regular expression
- using [HTMLEditorKit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) included in Swing
- using an HTML parser library like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

which one is best for you is for you to decide, an important consideration will be the dependencies it adds to your application - eg if you already have a desktop application a Swing dependency will probably not hurt, whereas in a server application this might not be the best possible idea.

Comment: <html><body>
<p><font size="2">I will be out of the office starting  09/24/2009 and will not return until 09/28/2009.<br>
</font><font size="2"><br> I have something like this which I want to save without the tags .
</font></body></html>

Comment: I understand that Neeha, and I pointed to three different ways to tackle that problem.  You can even scrape a starting point code off the website I linked to.

Comment: thanks for the inputs.I will try those.

Comment: np -but a vote for the answer would have been nice :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all HTML tags then take a look at [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).
The code below using Jsoup shouldc remove all the html tags and give you plain text.

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing all tags, leaving just the "text" of the tag content:

```
String text = str.replaceAll("(?m)<.*?>", "");
```

But it's not going to work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

HTML ***is*** a "readable" format. But if you're looking for something to abstract away the HTML-isms, there are several libraries you can look at. [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is one example. Mostly the keywords to look for here are "DOM", "HTML parser", and "XSS prevention".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to remove html tags.